# A message from The Federation of Binary Robots

Tags: cipher

The Federation of Binary Robots had a message, but their binary to English programme malfunctioned. Can you decipher it?
 2BQLH30DYS0JFZCL1SVNVZDZ2SSAESALJXIZN8WE2A86HSLCZNHP18VBTE47TE2K7ETKJ4S6XNLLCQ0XS2FK142X8GVW8H69G8VFLZQ5RN2SHHDZBWMQDFVYNNGK3I5PS3DL4WW7CD

Hint:

> Start with two binary zeros

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> YAY! A BANANA! TIME TO EAT!

Firstly we note that...

> The transmission appears to be in base 36. Converting to binary and prepending two zeros gives `0010110100101110001011010010110100100000001011100010110100100000001011010010111000101101001011010010000000101101001011100010110100101110001011010010110100100000001011110010000000101110001011010010000000101111001000000010110100101110001011100010111000100000001011100010110100100000001011010010111000100000001011100010110100100000001011010010111000100000001011100010110100100000001011010010111000101101001011100010110100101101001000000010111100100000001011010010000000101110001011100010000000101101001011010010000000101110001000000010111100100000001011010010000000101101001011010010110100100000001011110010000000101110001000000010111000101101001000000010110100100000001011010010111000101101001011100010110100101101`

We then see that

> The bits naturally divide up into 89 groups of 8 with the only groups being `001011101`, `00101110`, `00100000` and `00101111`.

... which correspond to

> The [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters `-` `.`   and `/` giving the string `-.-- .- -.-- -.-.-- / .- / -... .- -. .- -. .- -.-.-- / - .. -- . / - --- / . .- - -.-.--`

... which is clearly

> Morse code which [translates](https://morsecode.world/international/translator.html) into `YAY! A BANANA! TIME TO EAT!`